# To identify model of Liftmaster garage door opener

Tags: garage-door-opener

At my new house there's already a `Liftmaster` garage door opener working but even taking a closer look at its body, I don't know what model it is. Is there a way to tell?

Some pictures of the body if these help (I Googled `Part No` but haven't found anything specific):

[image]
[image]

(Reason I need to know the model is because I'm trying to linking a wireless opener (`GD00Z-4`), which claims to be compatible with most of the garage door openers out there, but I'm having an issue while installing it so want to confirm.)

Comment: Your controller will be compatible.  You might want to checkout Chamberlain/liftmaster'myQ controllers tho.  They retrofit to any model and include not only door control but also door status.

Comment: It is under the light cover on many models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many "brands" of opener, it's really a Chamberlain, and has a Chamberlain part number there on the label.

[image]